# How can I execute next script that wait for the previous script to complete first?

Tags: bash, docker, shell

In https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/creating-your-site/#previewing-as-you-write, there's a command that will launch my document site.

`docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8000 -v ${PWD}:/docs squidfunk/mkdocs-material`

I want that after it is launch, I will automatically open the browser and see it.

I write a script as below

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8000 -v ${PWD}:/docs squidfunk/mkdocs-material

open http://localhost:8000
```

But it turns out the `open` command cannot be triggered, as the previous `docker run` is still holding the process still.

If I use `&` as below, then the `open` will get called too fast before the page is ready

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8000 -v ${PWD}:/docs squidfunk/mkdocs-material &

open http://localhost:8000
```

How can I get `open` called at the right time?

(FYI, I'm using `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get open called at the right time?

Opening the browser at exactly the *right* time would require your server `mkdocs` to give some signal that it is ready. Since you probably don't want to modify the code of the server, you just have to wait for the right time and then open the page.

Either measure the startup time once by hand and then use a fixed wait time or check the page repeatedly until it loads.

In both cases, the docker command and the process of opening the page must run in parallel. bash can run run things in parallel using background jobs (`... &`). Since `docker -it` must run in the foreground, we run `open` as a the background job. This might seem a little strange, since we *seemingly* open the website before starting the server, but keep in mind that both commands run in parallel.

Either

```
# replace 2 with your measured time
sleep 2 && open http://localhost:8000 &
docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8000 -v "${PWD}:/docs" squidfunk/mkdocs-material
```

or

```
while ! curl http://localhost:8000 -s -f -o /dev/null; do
  sleep 0.2
done && open http://localhost:8000 &
docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8000 -v "${PWD}:/docs" squidfunk/mkdocs-material
```

Comment: I got this response when using "&", `the input device is not a TTY`

Comment: You need to change the docker command. `-it` probably causes this. Maybe try `-d` instead (see [manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d)). This might also require to alter the command used to start the server inside docker. I cannot help you with that as I am neither using docker nor mkdocs.

Comment: On the other hand... You could also put `open` in the background and run `docker` in the foreground. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds (to me) like:

- `docker run` is a blocking process (it does not exit and/or return control to the console) so ...
- the `open` is never run (unless the `docker run` command is aborted in which case the `open` will fail), and ...
- pushing `docker run` into the background means the `open` is run before the URL is fully functional

If this is the case I'm wondering if you could do something like:

```
docker run ... &                          # put in background, return control to console
sleep 3                                   # sleep 3 seconds
open ...
```

**NOTE:** manually picking the number of seconds to sleep (`3` in this case) isn't ideal but a decent number that guarantees URL availability **and** doesn't leave you hanging should be doable with some testing

Another 'basic' option might be a looping construct combined with a `sleep`, eg:

```
docker run ... &
while true                        # loop indefinitely
do
    sleep 1                       # sleep 1 sec
    open ...  2>/dev/null         # try the open
    [[ $? == 0 ]] && break        # if it doesn't fail then break out of loop, ie, 
                                  # if it does fail then repeat loop
done
```